# Value returned by an active radio button in meteor

Tags: jquery, meteor

I'm struggling to get the value of a selected radio button (in this case bootstrap 3 button group) when I close a modal form.

I'm getting the button correctly, but the only value I seem to be able to return is .text() which has a bunch of space around it. I could use this, but figure there must be a better way.

The html is

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-warning">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="requester" value="requester">Requester
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-warning active">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="packer" value="packer">Packer
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-info">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="admin" value="admin">Admin
  </label>
</div>
```

with the js I'm using, that responds to a "done" button

```
Template.addUserModalInner.events({
  'click .btn-primary': function(event, template) {
    console.log("Done clicked");
    var role = $('.btn-group > .btn.active');
    console.log(role);
    console.log(role.text());
```

The console.log(role) shows that I'm selection the correct button each time, but what I'd really like to get to is the value. I've tried .val(), .value, .id but no joy with any of these.

Where can I find a list of properties I can access (as a more general question) and is there a better way than .text() to get the selected button?

Ta
Peter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that the click events, as well as your selectors, are being performed on the `<label>` elements, not the `<input>` elements.  The labels contain text but do not have a value which is why the code is responding as it does.  You want the value of the label's child input.

You can get that using strategies you've named as well as others, for example:

```
var role = $('.btn-group > .btn.active > input').val();
```

Or, to limit the selector to your `addUserModalInner` template (the selector above is traversing the whole DOM):

```
var role = template.find('.btn-group > .btn.active > input').value;
```

Lastly, the easiest way to find the list of properties you can access per DOM element is in your browser's developer tools - under the `properties` tab in Chrome (and I imagine it is similar in other browsers) the label element will list other properties you can use to access the child input as above, for example `children` or `firstElementChild`.